# My SQL - return the rolls/ids from a where clause list which is not exist in table?

Tags: mysql, sql

The below query is a sample query. I am trying to get an idea from u guys. I wrote a query which return those results which has found in table but i used many rolls in where clause list, but all rolls are not found in database.

```
SELECT  roll,name,phone FROM my_tbl where roll in (1,2,3,4,5,6)

This query gives the result like

Roll    Name    Phone
2       name1   123
3       name2   345
6       name3   785

That query returns only those result which is stored into the table.    
But I want to get all of rolls which is used in clause (1,2,3,4,5,6).
My expecting result should be like 

 Roll   Name    Phone
    1       n/a      0
    2       name1   123
    3       name2   345
    4       n/a      0
    5       n/a      0
    6       name3   785

Is it possible ? If possible then how ?
```

Answer (score 0):

You need a derived table with the values:

```
select *
from (select 1 as roll union all
      select 2 as roll union all
      . . .
      select 6 as roll
     ) r left join
     my_tbl t
     using (roll);
```

This fills in the values for the unknown rolls with `NULL`, which seems like a suitable values.

Comment: I have 50k+ roll . So is it possible to write select 1 as roll union all ......... select 50000 as roll union all ???

Comment: @SSopno . . . You can do that.  I would think, though, that if you have so many then you have a table with all the values.  And you can use that table.